# JS, fetch() with forEach

Tags: javascript, json

To add into my index.js file I am given:
`const imgUrl = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/4"`

This is paired with the following html in my index.html:

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Intro to AJAX Practice Tasks</title>
    <script src="src/index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dog CEO</h1>

    <div id="dog-image-container">
      <!-- images here -->
    </div>

    <hr>
    <label for="select-breed">Filter Breeds That Start with:</label>
    <select id="breed-dropdown" name="select-breed">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
      <option value="d">d</option>
    </select>

    <ul id="dog-breeds">

    </ul>

  </body>
</html>
```

My requirements:

1. on page load, fetches the images using the url above
2. parses the response as JSON
3. adds image elements to the DOM for each image in the array

My unsuccessful attempt has taken me here:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', {
    const imgUrl = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/4"
    const imgElement = document.createElement('img')
    const div = document.getElementById('div')
    return fetch(imgUrl)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then (.forEach(img) => {
        imgElement.appendChild(div)
    })
})
```

I know that I am doing many things incorrectly. I cannot figure out how to append  to my  element using .forEach. Any input is appreciated. I am a student on day six and struggling.

Comment: `.then (.forEach(img) => { imgElement.appendChild(div) })` -> `.then(result => result.forEach(img) => { imgElement.appendChild(div) })`

Comment: Thanks for you response. The code is not fetching the images, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const imgUrl = "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random/4"
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const div = document.getElementById('dog-image-container');
    fetch(imgUrl)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            res.message.forEach((imgSrc) => {
                const img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = imgSrc;
                div.appendChild(img);
            })
        });
});
```

```html
<div id="dog-image-container">
      <!-- images here -->
    </div>
```

Comment: This is likely what the asker was looking for.

Comment: Wow. Thanks so much. i'm confused by ```res.message.forEach``` the rest of it I think I understand. Thanks again.

Comment: if you open the link  for getting 4 random images you will see that it return a JSON object with the following structure `{messages: string[], status: boolean}`

Comment: ok. so, the result is an object and I can dig into it by using .message because 'message' is a key inside the array. do i have that right? if, for instance, the key was 'popcorn' i could have done ```res.popcorn.foreach``` do i h ave that right?

Comment: yes, you get it right except for one thing.  'message' is a key inside the object not inside array.

Comment: ahh ok. the test I'm following said "array." This is tough as nails!